Will this large problem have a chance of being able to be solved?
I know this of course depends on the problem, but I want to know whether it is almost certainly impossible or not to solve my problem computationally with modern linear programming solvers before I spend a lot of time getting the data and implementing my problem.
I have a linear program with 200 million variables, and approximately (200 million) + (10k) constraints. The first set of 200 million constraints are extremely sparse. For each of these constraints, only at most 5 variables will have a nonzero coefficient. The remaining 10k constraints are also sparse. For each of these constraints, there will be at most 100 variables which have nonzero coefficient. Additionally, each variable is bounded below by 0.
The objective function is not sparse. Every variable has a nonzero cost.
I am thinking of using column generation to solve my problem. From the nature of my problem, I have determined that there are guaranteed to be at least 40 million variables which are nonzero at optimality (potentially more).
Does this have very little hope of being able to be solved by modern-day LP solvers?

PDLP (Google) solved problems with 92B nonzeros (https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.14535).

There's always a chance.  I don't think it's hitting the hard limits defined by Gurobi, so whether it can be solved will depend on the problem.

@Riley Unless the presolve can reduce the problem to nothing, Gurobi will run out of memory for this size.

I suspect first-order LP-solving (PDLP) will suffer from slow iteration speed due to memory-bandwith (a dot-product to calculate your objective touches ~3GB of memory!), simplex won't scale with the amount of constraints and higher-order LP-solving / IPMs won't fit into memory. PDLP has a cpu-based implementation in the ortools project as well as third-party GPU implementations (everything on github). You can (somewhat) quickly evaluate some dummy-problem with these characteristics to potentially observe negative results.

This is going to depend in part on your hardware. Your constraint matrix has potentially a billion or so nonzero coefficients, which means about 8GB or so just to store the matrix. Any chance the model can be decomposed?

Thanks for the comments everyone. One thing to note, I am using Xpress instead of Gurobi. I doubt that makes a significant difference, but potentially worth noting. Also, @prubin, I have access to an aws instance with 1536 GB of RAM and 192 CPUs. So I don't believe storing the constraint matrix would be an issue, right? Also, I don't as of yet see a way to decompose my model, but will of course explore that if I can.

@graphtheory123 Storing the matrix is one thing. Doing a factorization is more of a problem.

Bear in mind a version of the (factored) matrix will likely need to be stored for each live node in the search tree ... and that tree will likely be large.

@prubin This is about an LP not a MIP (I hope). 200 million integer variables would be really something.

@ErwinKalvelagen Yes it is an LP, not a MIP.

200 million variables on a 64-bit system (at 8 bytes per variable) is likely to take 1.6 GB RAM. That's without any overhead: presuming it's in an array and each variable is not wrapped in any way. Even if they are boolean variables, that should take 1 bit instead of 64 bits per variable, they typically do take 64 bits per variable.
Add in Variable wrapper classes, constraints, objective function, etc and you that 1.6 GB RAM turns into TB RAM requirements easily if you're not careful.
But what if you model it differently?
For example, if those are 200 million binary variables, consider using non-binary variables instead. It's a different approach and doesn't work for all solvers, but here's an illustration on how it works in our solver:


Note: some programming languages do support boolean taking up 1 bit when they are part of a boolean array. Most mainstream languages don't seem to support this yet. Either way, this only works if the boolean isn't wrapped in a Variable class (which creates extra overhead).

For example, in Java, the overhead for a single class instance is currently 12 bytes. A super simple class Variable with only a primitive boolean field takes 16 bytes. So 200 million of them in an array take 3.2 GB RAM. Best case scenario.
Java's Project Valhalla will heavily improve all this in future Java versions.

The number of variables is not so relevant. The number of nonzero elements in the LP matrix is a more important measure of size. Also, an LP has no binary variables.

Good point, I mistaking presumed a CP model.
